# Full width gallery with Masonry

Tags: html, css

I just founded this awesome gallery and implemented it but have one question. Is it possible to make it full width to be on both side of window and without space between images?
I believe this is the css that I need to change.

```
#content {
   /*width: 980px;*/
   /*width: 95%;*/
   width: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
   -webkit-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
   -moz-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
   -ms-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
   -o-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
   transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
} 

.featured {
   width: 620px;
}

.item img {
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
}

.featured img {
   width: 620px;
   height: auto;
}
```

This is the HTML part

```
<body>
<div id="content" class="container clearfix">

<div class="item">
  <img src="img/single-1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="img/single-2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="item featured">
  <img src="img/double-1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[JSFIDDLE of what is look like now](https://jsfiddle.net/e6yy4v8r/)

Comment: use JsFiddle to paste code/Demo,

Comment: Thank's for the comment. Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/e6yy4v8r/

Comment: You need to reference the masonry js in the fiddle - but change this: `margin: 0 20px 20px 0;` to this `margin: 0;` in the `.item` class and it should do it

Comment: I've added also reference the masonry js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your css:

```
#content {
 /*width: 980px;*/
 /*width: 95%;*/
 width: 100%; /* <-- change to 100% */
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 /*margin: 0 20px 20px 0;*/ /* comment out or remove this line */
 -webkit-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
 -moz-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
 -ms-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
 -o-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
 transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
}
```

Its adding margin / white space / gaps

Comment: This way it's remove only the space but didn't make the full width on the page.

Comment: this remove the space only on images one under another but not in the left and right. Also still didn't stretch them to the both sides of the window/page .. hm something is not quite right. I've using this with bootstrap. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Ahhhh ok - it could be, you'd have create an instance of it on something like bootply so we can test

Comment: This one? http://www.bootply.com/vyfWNeOrSW .. I can't find where to add reference to Masonry

Comment: The width 100% is in `#content`, not .`item`

Comment: On your Jsfiddle is on both places. In bootly example is in `#content` but still..

Comment: that's not my fiddle - it was done by someone else - you need to look at masonry options i think, this is a different style layout

Comment: Ok, thank's I'll accept your answer it gives me some points where and what should I try/search.

Comment: Thanks john, give me a shout if I can help further, I've done a lot of work with masonry stuff - also look for a code named freewall - I've used that before, it creates a more metro layout like you're after